# GetWeekYear and GetWeek in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

How GetWeekYear and GetWeek is calculating week and year? Is it ISO year and ISO week?

In documentation https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#get-week-year there is no info about that.

Comment: I've just checked for 2014-12-31 and 2015-01-01 and it returns year 2015 and week 1 for both. It seems that ISO values are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDF will actually call: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getWeekyear()

Joda Time uses ISO8601 standard.